# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

My Jquery code is recieving following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
         $('#CustomButton').click(function() {
        $('#CustomPickedTable tbody').append(
            $('<tr/>', {
                click: function() {
                    $(this).remove()
                },
                html: $("<td />", {
                    html: $("#CustomQuestionText").val(),
                    'data-attr-id': 5

                })
            })
        );
        return false;
    });​
});      // <--- This line recieves the error
</script>
```

This is my mark up for this jquery code:

```
<table id="CustomPickedTable" class="box-style2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Valda frågor</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<p>Lägg till egen fråga</p>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.CustomQuestionText, new { @class = "selectstyle", @id = "CustomQuestionText" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomQuestionText)
</div>
<div>
    <p><input type="button" id="CustomButton"  value="Lägg till" /></p>
</div>
</div>
```

what may cause this error how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code seems fine. The error is probably related to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copy the code to notepad++ I get: (note the ?)

```
 $(function() {
         $('#CustomButton').click(function() {
        $('#CustomPickedTable tbody').append(
            $('<tr/>', {
                click: function() {
                    $(this).remove()
                },
                html: $("<td />", {
                    html: $("#CustomQuestionText").val(),
                    'data-attr-id': 5

                })
            })
        );
        return false;
    });?
});      // <--- This line recieves the error
```

Fixed it and changes function() to document.ready for clarity:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#CustomButton').click(function() {
        $('#CustomPickedTable tbody').append(
            $('<tr/>', {
                click: function() {
                    $(this).remove()
                },
                html: $("<td />", {
                    html: $("#CustomQuestionText").val(),
                    'data-attr-id': 5

                })
            })
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

second last line after semicolon there is a special char i just remove this now try again with this code

```
$(function() {
             $('#CustomButton').click(function() {
            $('#CustomPickedTable tbody').append(
                $('<tr/>', {
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).remove()
                    },
                    html: $("<td />", {
                        html: $("#CustomQuestionText").val(),
                        'data-attr-id': 5

                    })
                })
            );
            return false;
        });​
    });      // <--- This line recieves the error
```

Answer (score 0):

Contains some illegal character in second last line. Removed it and it worked.

[image]